# Redirect with data in Django

Tags: python, django, redirect, request

I have a user authorization through a link:

```
def ClientAuth(request, link_code):
try:
    code = Links.objects.filter(code=link_code).values('code', 'status')
    if code[0]['status']:
        username, password = 'Client', '**************'
        client = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if client is not None:
            login(request, client)
            return redirect('clientPage')

        return HttpResponse("Hello its work")
    else:
        return render(request, 'client/404.html')
except:
    return render(request,'client/404.html')
```

If the link exists in the database and the active one authorizes us as a client and redirects it to his page, it looks like this in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('clientPage/',views.clientPage, name = 'clientPage'),
   path('<link_code>/', views.ClientAuth, name='ClienAuth')
]
```

My task is that, depending on the link the client used to log in on the client page, he receives different information, for example, the link ID

Is there any way I can pass this data from the ClientAuth function when redirecting?

redirect to this page:

```
def clientPage(request):
    print(request)
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Comment: use something like this `redirect('my_function', args=(backend,))`

Comment: But normal redirect doesn't seem to accept arguments, and resolve only accepts arguments to the link @FerhatMousavi

Comment: No you can do that just read [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: there are an example for kwargs `redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')` you can use args as mentioned before.

Comment: but shouldn't the arguments in this case belong to the link to which the redirect goes?
It's just that I need to leave the link in the form in which it is written in the urls

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want it to appear on your rendered page. If so, you need to send it to HTML as context_data and add it wherever you want with jinja by put it between {{ link_code }}. if this HTML is rendered by other view you can send it to that view by redirect with parameter then put it on context_data.

Comment: Just use django [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/).  So you save the information in your `ClientAuth` view, like `request.session['link'] = ...` then you can access that in the information in your `clientPage` view in this manner: `request.session.get('link')`, add it to the context, and there you have it.  The only issue might be if the user is using private or incognito mode on their browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change urls as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('clientPage/<link_code>',views.clientPage, name = 'clientPage'),
   path('<link_code>/', views.ClientAuth, name='ClienAuth')
]
```

then change the views as below:

```
def ClientAuth(request, link_code):
try:
    code = Links.objects.filter(code=link_code).values('code', 'status')
    if code[0]['status']:
        username, password = 'Client', '**************'
        client = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if client is not None:
            login(request, client)
            return redirect('clientPage', link_code=link_code)

        return HttpResponse("Hello its work")
    else:
        return render(request, 'client/404.html')
except:
    return render(request,'client/404.html')


def clientPage(request, link_code=''):
    print(request)
    context = {'link_code': link_code}
    return render(request, 'test_app/index.html', context)
```